# identifying if the character is a digit or Unicode character within a word in python

Tags: python, regex, unicode-string, tamil

I want to find if a word contains digit and characters and if so separate the digit part and the character part. I want to check for tamil words, ex: `ரூ.100` or `ரூ100`. I want to seperate the `ரூ.` and `100`, and `ரூ` and `100`. How do i do it in python. I tried like this:

```
    for word in f.read().strip().split(): 
      for word1, word2, word3 in zip(word,word[1:],word[2:]): 
        if word1 == "ர" and word2 == "ூ " and word3.isdigit(): 
           print word1 
           print word2 
        if word1.decode('utf-8') == unichr(0xbb0) and word2.decode('utf-8') == unichr(0xbc2): 
           print word1 print word2
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried checking if the first character is ரூ and if it is followed by a digit, but the problem was that i could not match with the unicode value, it throws an error.

Comment: this is what i tried:                                            for word in f.read().strip().split():
 for word1, word2, word3 in zip(word,word[1:],word[2:]):
    if word1 == "ர" and word2 == "ூ " :
#and word3.isdigit():
     print word1
     print word2
    if word1.decode('utf-8') == unichr(0xbb0) and word2.decode('utf-8') == unichr(0xbc2):
     print word1
     print word2

Comment: @Ismail Badawi but i also want to 100 and ஆம் in words like 100ஆம், so i thought the above code would anyways not be generic, so left it.

Comment: @charvi: post your code in your question. With formatting.

Comment: @smci: from next time i will post my code in question. thank u.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `(.*?)(\d+)(.*)` regular expression, that will save 3 groups: everything before digits, digits and everything after:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = ur'(.*?)(\d+)(.*)'
>>> s = u"ரூ.100"
>>> match = re.match(pattern, s, re.UNICODE)
>>> print match.group(1)
ரூ.
>>> print match.group(2)
100
```

Or, you can unpack matched groups into variables, like this:

```
>>> s = u"100ஆம்"
>>> match = re.match(pattern, s, re.UNICODE)
>>> before, digits, after = match.groups()
>>> print before

>>> print digits
100
>>> print after
ஆம்
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried the first pattern matching you said and it works... Thank u. Il try the other one too.

Comment: thank u very much! the second one u said works too!!

Answer (score 1):

Use unicode properties:

`\pL` stands for a letter in any language
`\pN` stands for a digit in any language.

In your case it could be:

```
(\pL+\.?)(\pN+)
```